# Find $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)<0$ for all $x$. $f''(x)(|x|-1)>0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm\infty}f(x)=-x$

Tags: calculus

I am not sure if this problem belongs to this community, down vote if not, wont mind that

Comment: well i tried many, i did not find anything that a satisfies, will post if i find anything. i am kind of directionless

Comment: The final condition, $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=-x$ doesn't make sense. The right side is a function of $x$ but the left side isn't.

Comment: Presumably they mean $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{f(x)}{-x} = 1$.

Comment: It'd be better to replace the sentence in the post with something relevant to the mathematical question. Do you understand what $f''(x)(|x|-1)>0$ has to do with the sign of $f''$, and with the concavity of $f$?

Comment: OP could also mean that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \pm \infty}|f(x)+x| = 0$.

Comment: @Holycow: Please edit your Question so the body asks about a mathematical problem.  The title is close to making sense, but not quite there, and the editorial content of the body doesn't help the Reader willing to lend a hand... or interested in some learning!

Answer (score 2):

A solution is given by the function

$$f(x)=-x+e^{-\frac12x^2}.$$

What is the idea behind the solution?

If we write $f(x)=-x+g(x)$ then we have to find a function $g(x)$ satisfying $g'(x)<1,$ $g$ convex on $(-\infty,-1)\cup (1,\infty),$ concave on $(-1,1)$ and such that $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}g(x)=0.$ A known function convex outside a neighbourhood of zero, concave on a neigbourhood of zero, and converging to zero at infinite is the Gaussian function with mean zero, that is, giving by the expression $e^{-ax^2}.$ Giving the value $a=1/2$ we can check that all conditions are satisfied.

Comment: ...Sorry for the repeated edits. You need to rescale to $f(x)=-x+e^{-x^2/2}$ so that the change in concavity occurs at $\pm 1$. Right now it changes at $\pm 1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Ian I have realized after you first comment. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is that $f''(x)(|x|-1)>0$ will equal to 0 if $x=$ 1 or -1, unless $f''(x) \sim \frac{C}{|x|-1}$, with $C>0$. Then you can try to integrate.